# Scala: difference of two sets by key

Tags: scala, set, diff

I have two sets of `(k,v)` pairs:

```
val x = Set((1,2), (2,10), (3,5), (7,15))
val y = Set((1,200), (3,500))
```

How to find difference of these two sets by keys, to get:

```
Set((2,10),(7,15))
```

Any quick and simple solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val ym = y.toMap
x.toMap.filterKeys(k => !(ym contains k)).toSet
```

Sets don't have keys, maps do.  So you convert to map.  Then, you can't create a difference on maps, but you can filter the keys to exclude the ones you don't want.  And then you're done save for converting back to a `Set`. (It's not the most efficient way to do this, but it's not bad and it's easy to write.)

Answer (score 2):

Let `val keys = y.map(_._1).toSet` be the set of keys (first element in the pair) that must not occur as key in `x`; thus

```
for ( p <- x if !keys(p._1) ) yield p
```

as well as

```
x.collect { case p@(a,b) if !keys(a) => p }
```

and

```
x.filter ( p => !keys(p._1) )
x.filterNot ( p => keys(p._1) )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
 x filter{ m => y map{_._1} contains m._1} toSet
```